# How to determine whether NMinimize returns a solution or not?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm using `NMinimize` to find the minimum solution for a non-linear objective function. As I change the set of constraints, most of times `NMinimize` cannot yield a solution, because there is none subject to the constraints that I'm using. Hence, I want to use a `While` loop, which keeps going until `NMinimize` ultimately returns a solution.

However, I don't know how to determine whether `NMinimize` can yield a solution or not at each iteration of the `While` loop. Any idea would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide an example of your objective function and a few sets of constraints that you are working with? It is hard to say anything meaningful in such a general scenario.

Comment: From the docs `If NMinimize determines that the constraints cannot be satisfied, it returns {Infinity,{x->Indeterminate,\[Ellipsis]}}.`